# Multicatching or Exception Hierarchy

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

What's more consistent with Clean Code. Using Multicatching or creating a superclass Exception and catch it.

```
try {
      //some action     
} catch (Exception1 | Exception2 e) {
      //some action after exception    
}
```

or

```
Exception1 extends SuperClassException  
Exception2 extends SuperClassException

try {
       //some action     
} catch (SuperClassException e) {
      //some action after exception    
}
```

Comment: Depends if  you want to treat differently this alternatives use cases or not.

Comment: If the second approach was good all java developer would catch Throwable always!

Comment: The behavior is to be the same for a family of exceptions. Currently, the hierarchy is already there. I wonder if there are better 9 exceptions or just one superclass

Comment: What if yet introduce and throw another subtype of SuperClassException? Do you also want to handle it same way as previous two ones? First case gives you guarantee that compiler will tell you where you didn't handle that third type, second case will handle it same way as other subtypes.

Comment: @Pshemo 
Your question suggests that approach 2 requires a higher entry level, because you need to understand the hierarchy of exceptions well. In the first case, we can add a specific type of exception to the catch. 
It seems to me that this may be more important than reducing the number line of code.

Comment: In short use `catch(CommonAncestor e)` if you want to handle *all* subtypes of that ancestor *in same way*. Use `catch(X | Y e)` if you want to handle on *specific* subtypes same way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to consider the circumstances. If the hierarchy is already there and you want to catch all classes from a specific hierarchy branch - you may very well go with catching the superclass.

Having said that, I would definitely not create an additional structure just to reduce the lines - especially if there is no clear IS-dependency between the exceptions and you are creating a superclass just based on a instinct, that "maybe these two belong together, because I am catching them at the same place". You are reducing the lines, but creating additional complexity in the class hierarchy - which IMHO makes code much harder to analyse and increases the time needed to predict its behavior.

Answer (score 3):

> What's more consistent with Clean Code. Using Multicatching or creating a superclass Exception and catch it.

Clean code doesn't really a help here. As I can't think of any distinct rule that point towards to one of the two options. Thus I think this boils down to (personal/team) style.

In the end, both approaches have their pros and cons:

The first one is more verbose, as it tells you **exactly** which exceptions will be caught. You look at it, and you know.

The second one hides that fact as you really don't see "how many" exceptions might fall into that category. But of course, to a certain degree, you have the same problem with the multi catch, as you could catch one or more basic exception types with that, too.

From that point of view, my recommendation would be:

- when you have *few* distinct exceptions, then simply list those (especially when there is currently no distinct super class that you could use instead)
- when no specific type information is required, then sure, catch only one super type thing

Answer (score 2):

**The latter, as long as your project defines the superclass and all subclasses are equally relevant to your catch clause and are to be handled the same way.**

Using fewer Exception types in your code enhances readability and therefore reduces the mental burden of other developers when they have to read it. However, this advantage is lost when there are semantic differences between catching the superclass and individual relevant subclasses.

However, should one of your subclassed Exceptions require special treatment when thrown, or is of particular interest to your logging methodologies, then you will want to use separate catch blocks.

Comment: Nice answer ... btw: is that your real last name (our neightbors are Schäfers, too, also living in BaWü).